# RTK recall api when set new state

Tags: react-native, rtk-query

I have a api with rtk (redux-toolkit) with a state 'search'

```
const [search, setSearch] = useState({nexToken: null})

const { data, isLoading, isError } = useGetPostQuery(search ?? skipToken)

useEffect(() => {
 console.log('data', data)
}, [data])
```

When I call methods to add parameters to my search and set the new state does not happen again the api, why?

for example:

```
const addCity = () => {
 const newFilter = { city: 'London. }
 setSearch({...search, ...newFilter})
}
```

Comment: This should generally work. I assume that you are omitting some code that might be important for this. Could you add some more code?
Also, add a `console.log(search)` after your `useState` to make sure state actually changes.

Comment: console.log(search) // {city: 'London', nextToken: null}

Comment: And then it makes a request I assume - what exactly is the behaviour you expect and what is happening?

Comment: expect: when I set a new search that launches a new call api. But now it does not perform an API call. Now I resolved with useLazy

Comment: Could you please add more code. like adding in the useGetPostQuery definition. Exactly tell us the problem what are you trying to achieve but unable to. Somewhat like what is Actual(what is happening) vs expected(what is desired). It might give more insights to the underlying problem you are facing and other devs might be able to help you out. @fabio87